# Find last row and column in VBA for a selected area

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the last row and the last column of an area I select in the sheet.

typically I use this to find last row and column:

```
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

However these lines are for Row = 1 and Column = 1.

let say I have a table elsewhere. I want to select the table and run the code. Then I want the following variables:

```
FirstRowTable = 
LastRowTable =   
FirstColumnTable = 
LastColumnTable =
```

I tried somehting like this, but it is not working:

```
LastRowTable = Selection.Row + Selection.Rows.Count - 1
FirstRowTable = Selection.Row
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? That code works for me. Please provide a [mcve]. In any event -- such code is often indicative of over-reliance on `Selection`. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4996248)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may put your selection into Range object and use it's rows and columns properties:

```
Dim selectionRange As range

Dim firstRow As Long, firstCol As Long, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long

Set selectionRange = Selection

firstRow = selectionRange.Cells(1, 1).row
firstCol = selectionRange.Cells(1, 1).column
lastRow = selectionRange.Cells(selectionRange.Rows.Count, 1).row
lastCol = selectionRange.Cells(1, selectionRange.Columns.Count).column
```

It's like you're scaling your worksheet to smaller size. `Range.Cells(1,1)` will be the upper left cell in your defined or named range and so on just like with worksheet.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some of the parameters of `Selected` rectangular range:

```
Sub range_reporter()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim nLastRow As Long, nLastColumn As Long
    Dim nFirstRow As Long, nFirstColumn As Long

    Set r = Selection

    nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
    MsgBox ("last row " & nLastRow)

    nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1
    MsgBox ("last column " & nLastColumn)

    nFirstRow = r.Row
    MsgBox ("first row " & nFirstRow)

    nFirstColumn = r.Column
    MsgBox ("first column " & nFirstColumn)

    numrow = r.Rows.Count
    MsgBox ("number of rows " & numrow)

    numcol = r.Columns.Count
    MsgBox ("number of columns " & numcol)

    s = r.Address
    MsgBox ("address " & s)

    s = r(1).Address
    MsgBox ("address of first cell " & s)
    MsgBox ("worksheet " & r.Worksheet.Name)

    MsgBox ("workbook  " & r.Worksheet.Parent.Name)

    MsgBox ("item count " & r.Count)

    '
    'sub-ranges
    '
    MsgBox "address of first row " & r.Rows(1).Address
    MsgBox "address of first column " & r.Columns(1).Address
End Sub
```

Comment: This is probably useful to OP so +1, but your method of calculating first and last row are identical to OP's way (except that you used a range variable) so it leaves mysterious their claim that it isn't working. My guess is OP has an unrelated bug in their actual code and has misdiagnosed its source.

Comment: Hi guys, 

Thank you so much! Very Kind of you. 

Okay, So I tried all codes, but I still get an error in the "Selection".
It says: Compile error: Expected Function or variable.

However, I tried to open a new document and implemented the code, and everything was fine. Very strange.

Comment: @Learning_script Sounds like you might have defined a sub or function called `Selection` in your original code (or something along those line). Also, somewhat phantom bugs can be reduced if you use `Option Explicit` at the top of each module. Are you doing that?

Comment: oh my god! I am so stupid. I had a code elsewhere, which was called "Selection". I deleted that, and everything is now working fine :)
I am still learning!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could use the address property of the range/table:

```
Sub Test3()

    Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim FirstColumn As Long, LastColumn As Long
    Dim RowCount As Long

    FirstRow = Range(Split(Selection.Address, ":")(0)).Row
    FirstColumn = Range(Split(Selection.Address, ":")(0)).Column
    LastRow = Range(Split(Selection.Address, ":")(1)).Row
    LastColumn = Range(Split(Selection.Address, ":")(1)).Column
    RowCount = Selection.Rows.Count


    'If using a table you can also use:
    'FirstRow = Range(Split(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table6").Range.Address, ":")(0)).Row

    MsgBox "First Row: " & FirstRow & vbCr & _
           "Last Row: " & LastRow & vbCr & _
           "First Column: " & FirstColumn & vbCr & _
           "Last Column: " & LastColumn & vbCr & _
           "Row Count: " & RowCount

End Sub
```

This will fail if the selection is a single cell as it won't be able to split the address string by the `:`.

Edit - but as @JohnColeman mentioned, this doesn't solve why your code doesn't work.